# How to include a shared library in C++? libORB_SLAM

Tags: c++

Im trying to use a shared lib and so far had no luck.
The lib is called libORB_SLAM2.so and gets compiled with the code from:

https://github.com/MathewDenny/ORB_SLAM2

Anyways I did copy over the mono_tum code from the Example folder in my own project (just this single file) and tried
to compile it just using the shared lib. It says "System.h" not found. 
Could anybody chime in?

Thanks!

edit: OS: ubuntu 12.04 gcc 4.6, I've used the following linker command:
gcc -L/home/user/Desktop/program/libs/lib  -Wall -std=c++11 -o test mono_tum.cc -lORB_SLAM2.so
fatal error: System.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

For the System.h check the github link (include folder)

Comment: Provide your OS environment, a [MCVE] and the linker command you used please. `System.h` isn't a standard c++ header.

Comment: I've added some informations! I hope that will be enough. As for the source code wouldnt make sense to post the whole thing as it is a bigger library. Therefore I was posting the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get here

```
error: System.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

Is a compiler error, not a linker error. It tells you that the compiler can not find the file "System.h", included in line 29 of mono_turn.cc:

```
#include<System.h>
```

You can find the file in the repository's "Include" directory. So tell your compiler also, where to find it. Use something like

```
gcc ... -I/path/to/your/repository/clone/Include ...
```

Then, you should ensure that the library (filename is libORB_SLAM2.so) is where you tell the linker to search for libraries, you do this already with

```
gcc ... L/home/user/Desktop/program/libs/lib
```

so

```
ls L/home/user/Desktop/program/libs/lib/libORB_SLAM2.so
```

should output a valid ls listing, just to be sure. Note that, by convention, the lib prefix and the .so suffix are not passed to the linker, so change your gcc flags to

```
gcc ... -lORB_SLAM2
```

So, as a next step I'd try to compile your project with

```
gcc -L/home/user/Desktop/program/libs/lib -I/path/to/your/repository/clone/Include -Wall -std=c++11 -o test mono_tum.cc -lORB_SLAM2
```